Count number of products for past 3 month for each row in a table - SQL sliding window in Snowflake
I have below table in Snowflake db.



Product_name
Shipping_date
Status




Mobile
2024-06-14
shipped


Mobile
2024-05-15
not_shipped


Mobile
2023-05-10
not_shipped


Mobile
2023-04-25
shipped


Mobile
2023-04-20
shipped


Laptop
2023-04-10
shipped


Laptop
2023-11-09
shipped



I need to count the number of products shipped and not_shipped for past 3 months from each shipping date. For example:



Prodcut
shipping_date
shipped_T3Months
not_shipped_T3Months




Mobile
2024-06-14
0
0


Mobile
2024-05-15
1
0


Mobile
2023-05-10
1
1


Mobile
2023-04-25
1
2


Mobile
2023-04-20
2
2


Laptop
2023-04-10
0
0


Laptop
2023-12-09
0
0



I need to perform this in Snowflake SQL which does not support the sliding window with interval keyword.
I can write the query as below but it won't work because of interval keyword.
SELECT 
    Product
   , shipping_date
   , COUNT(case when status = 'shipped') OVER (
            ORDER BY record_date
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '3' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       ) AS count_last_three_months_shipped
    , COUNT(case when status = 'not_shipped') OVER (
            ORDER BY record_date
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '3' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
       ) AS count_last_three_months_not_shipped
FROM 
    my_table

Is there any other efficient way to perform this operation as I'm working with significantly larger table.

I'd do something like this:
WITH products_dates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Product
    , shipping_date
    FROM 
        my_table
)
SELECT
    pd.Product
   , pd.shipping_date
   , COUNT(case when mt.status = 'shipped' then 1 end) AS count_last_three_months_shipped
   , COUNT(case when mt.status = 'not_shipped' then 1 end) AS count_last_three_months_not_shipped
FROM 
    products_dates pd
    JOIN
    my_table mt
    ON mt.shipping_date BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(pd.shipping_date, -3) AND pd.shipping_date
GROUP BY
     pd.Product
   , pd.shipping_date

If my_table doesn't have (product, shipping_date) as a key, then it's the only working way.
And if it does, then it still works, you just may remove DISTINCT from products_dates
